# Add Layout in custom folder instead layout folder in android

Tags: android, android-layout

can i add layout.xml, R.java and string.xml files in my folder?

[image]

**Code:**

**NetconnectionFailureActivity.java:(My Sample Name)**

```
package stack.api.netfailure;

import sync.api.netfailure.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class NetconnectionFailureActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    }
}
```

**CheckActivity.java:(My Activity -> have to convert this into jar file)**

```
package stack.api.check;

import sync.api.netfailure.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CheckActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checklayout);

    }

}
```

If i have added this jar file to new project named "CheckingJarFile", and my layout in layout folder, it will crash as "`import sync.api.netfailure.R not found`". Please any one tell me how to convert my layout, my R.java file with myactivity into one package name?

Comment: Why to complicate.. simply NO!!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got a Solution by trying like below,

- I have created one project with my activity, my layout, my R.java(generated automatically)
- Clean and Build the project.
- Now Created one sample, added what are the permissions needed.
- Added same layout in this sample.
- Renamed Manifest file and layout file in my project
- Now convert My [Project into jar](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html) file
- Referred this [jar file into sample](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm)

**Note:** My project will throw an error "`Manifest file is missing`", but after converting into jar file and referred in sample, `Sample is Working Good`.

Otherwise we can create layout dynamically.

Comment: Good work that is.. Thanks for sharing it. This wil help someone. And don't forget the mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @AndroSelva: Thank you Selva... Sure, i can accept it by tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't do it.

You have to `add only .java file in folder` and `Don't add R.java,its auto-generated file.`
and `string.xml in res->values->string.xml`

Comment: ok, if i have added 2 layouts in res folder, used in my own activity and converted this activity into jar file. if the customer uses this jar file in his own sample using this activity, then it will crash with package name... how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do that. Your layout xmls and String xmls are resources which will be used by Android, and if not found your code will crash. So the structure specifies clearly that layout has to be specified in the layout directory and similarly the Strings.xml in values directory. And also R.java is not something what we can play around with. Its system generated. Copying it to some other directory makes its another java class and not the Resource tracker.

Comment: ok, if i have added 2 layouts in res folder, used in my own activity and converted this activity into jar file. if the customer uses this jar file in his own sample using this activity, then it will crash with package name... how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try importing your package into the class?

Comment: see, my checkactivity in one package name. layouts is in another package. if i have given my jar file, then customer has to import checkpackage(stack.api.check) only, not layouts package(stack.api.netfailure)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not possible. When you copy R.java file in your own folder and recompile the project, it again recreates R.java in gen folder with an error "The type R is already defined".

Comment: ok, if i have added 2 layouts in res folder, used in my own activity and converted this activity into jar file. if the customer uses this jar file in his own sample using this activity, then it will crash with package name... how to solve this?